cURL in bash script reads $HOME as /root/
OS in question is Fedora 40.
I would like to create a directory and download a file to it, so I wrote this simple script
#!/bin/bash

set -eu -o pipefail 

sudo -n true
test $? -eq 0 || exit 1

curlpackages="$HOME/curl-packages"
mkdir -p $curlpackages
curl --output-dir $curlpackages -JLO <someaddress>

I would expect the directory and file to be under /home/myname/ but instead I get /root/ . Is this because I run this with sudo? If so, can I use another variable instead of $HOME to point to my home folder instead of root?

What's the point of the sudo -n true? You aren't actually switching to root there, why are you doing it? And why are you running this as root at all? Nothing there requires root and, actually, it is wrong to run it as root since that will change ownsership, as you saw.

You can use $SUDO_USER

SUDO_USER
Set to the login name of the user who invoked sudo.

#!/bin/bash

set -eu -o pipefail 

sudo -n true
test $? -eq 0 || exit 1

userhome=$(eval echo "~$SUDO_USER")
curlpackages="$userhome/curl-packages"
mkdir -p "$curlpackages"
curl --output-dir "$curlpackages" -JLO <someaddress>

Sudo Manual
Identify user in a Bash script called by sudo
SUDO_USER is documented in man sudo

This seems to add unnecessary complexity, we are using eval adding an an extra variable and spawning a sub shell. The only way you can get the root directory is if you become root. @yuropoor could you check that please? do whoami if it comes up as root then do exit, thensudo bash script.bash that way you wouldn't need to change anything or add more code by just fixing your approach, if was a beginner looking at this I'd have no idea how it works, I'd just use it because it works (not good if you're new), going overkill like this bloats the code

Yeah, you could get the home with userhome=$(awk -F: -v user="$SUDO_USER" '$1==user{print $6}' /etc/passwd) instead.

impressive @terdon :D


Is this because I run this with sudo?

yes

If so, can I use another variable instead of $HOME to point to my home folder instead of root?

Why not put your sudo command inside the script - for only those commands which need to be run as root, rather than running the whole script as root:
Note that, for example sudo echo $HOME will print your expected home directory - because the expansion of that variable happens before the command is executed.

To clear up some confusion Nickotine in the comments has regarding this answer:
$ cat > test.sh
echo $HOME
^C

$ sh test.sh
/home/dev

$ sudo sh test.sh
/root


Why not put your sudo command inside the script - maybe a wrong approach, but I want this script to be executable only by someone with sudo access - there will be more things in there, so I prefer 'run it as sudo, if you can't, don't touch it' approach. Thank you for answer :)

@Yuropoor you have the sudo -n true test already there, so why not just put an error message there saying the user doesn't have required sudo privileges?

ok I found out why our results differ. on Mac when you do sudo bash test.sh you get the user directory whereas on linux you get the root dir.

You'll have to specify your user like this since you are root:
curlpackages='/home/<yourUser>/curl-packages'
Although the sudo command you have in your script just checks if the user has permissions to use the sudo command.

Did you become root like: sudo -i or su?
If so then exit and run script like: sudo bash script.bash
Then you shouldn't have to change anything
Doing validation on the exit code is not required, sudo -n true will not allow the script to run by users with no sudo permissions
You are validating the same thing twice

Here's what I mean, some improvements on your code:
#!/bin/bash

set -eu -o pipefail 

sudo -n true

curlpackages='/home/<yourUser>/curl-packages'
mkdir -p $curlpackages
curl --output-dir $curlpackages -JLO <someaddress>


If you write the script like this then you avoid using eval, an extra variable, and having to use command substitution or $() which starts a sub-shell, and can lead to unintended side effects
See this about the security risks/ disadvantages of using eval
The code is compact and easier to read, and redundancy has been reduced

